# como consultar el rif seniat Venezuela

Tags: javascript, php, python

Trato poder extraer la información fiscal del contribuyente, mediante su rif.

Este link http://contribuyente.seniat.gob.ve/BuscaRif/BuscaRif.jsp es un formulario
y aparte hay que ingresar un captcha

Esto no funciona

```php
        $url = "http://contribuyente.seniat.gob.ve/getContribuyente/getrif?rif=J003360392";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://seniat.gob.ve');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
        $html=curl_exec($ch);
        echo $html;
```

Este otro tampoco funciona

```php
        $url = "http://www.elrif.com/?rif=J003360392";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://seniat.gob.ve');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
        $html=curl_exec($ch);
        echo $html;
```

Al parecer el único que funciona es el sitio oficial, pero como un formulario captcha.

La pagina oficial si entrega los datos, pero hay que hacerlo a mano y escribir el bendito captcha.

Por ejemplo si abro la pagina http://contribuyente.seniat.gob.ve/BuscaRif/BuscaRif.jsp sale la imagen captcha y tomo su valor ejemplo: **196cyt** y en otra pestaña abro http://contribuyente.seniat.gob.ve/BuscaRif/BuscaRif.jsp?p_rif=JJ003360392&codigo=196cyt si que me da los resultados

Pero si intento hacerlo por curl

```php
        $url = "http://contribuyente.seniat.gob.ve/BuscaRif/BuscaRif.jsp?p_rif=JJ003360392&codigo=196cyt";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
        $html=curl_exec($ch);
        echo $html;
```

Imprime la pagina y dice **EL codigo no coincide con la imagen**

Lo que pretendo es crear un código o una api, para poder implementarlo en una pagina de punto de venta, donde el operador solo tipee el numero de cedula o rif y traer de vuelta la información fiscal del contribuyente.

¡Necesito ayuda por favor!

Comment: No entiendo porque no usa el: "del sitio oficial"

Comment: ¿Esto te sirve?: [seniat.php](https://github.com/willicab/infove-api/blob/master/clases/seniat.php)

Comment: @DanielBriceño Amigo gracias por responder, estoy creando un punto de venta y necesito extraer los datos fiscales cuando el operador escriba el rif o cedula

Comment: ¿Te sirvio?. . .. .. ..

Comment: Haz probado hacerlo por curl?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Extraer la informacion fiscal del portal seniat rif](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/590710/extraer-la-informacion-fiscal-del-portal-seniat-rif)