# Extraer la informacion fiscal del portal seniat rif

Tags: javascript, php, python

Revisando este código que funcionaba muy bien hasta hace algún tiempo,
cuando el `SENIAT` coloco un validador de caracteres en la pagina de consulta
todo cambio y ahora es imposible extraer la información!

```php
    $rif=J310029539;
    $url="http://contribuyente.seniat.gob.ve/BuscaRif/BuscaRif.jsp?p_rif=$rif";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // almacene en una variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $xxx1 = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    // Separamos el resultado en un arreglo y dividirlo por \n\r\n
    $xxx = explode("\n\r\n", $xxx1);
    // Con este comando podemos ver toda la pantalla de seniat impresa por reglones de arreglos
    // print_r($xxx);
    // Impreme el rif y la razon social
    print_r($xxx[6]);
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como se puede hacer ahora?
estuve revisando el tema de las `OCR` pero parece un poco complicado

Comment: Justamente, si agregaron el captcha es para que no hagas esto!... si fuera facil de saltear, usarian otro, o el de imagenes, e igual te lo complicarian... No, no es por aca por donde tenes que ir. Si no tienen una API de acceso, no vas a poder hacerlo.....

Comment: Sugiero que utilices Selenium para automatizar el navegador. De ese modo tendrás la chance de completar el captcha manualmente.

Comment: Hola Grupo ZUCOL, bienvenido, volver a hacer la misma pregunta no está bien visto, cuando te cierran una pregunta, la idea es que la edites para acomodara a los lineamientos del sitio, para que así, sea reabierta, por otro lado, es bastante difícil que encuentres aquí la respuesta, al ser tan específica de un organismo y de un país, yo intentaría buscar información en el propio organismo...

Comment: La tarea es un poco compleja, soy de Vzla y que yo sepa no existe un API. Se me ocurre que leas la imagen usando **tesseract** pero vaya que es complicado hacer eso. Otra forma sería leer la imagen con https://cloud.google.com/vision?hl=es pero solo te permiten 1000 consultas al mes. Cómo el tema me interesa investigare para ver cómo se pueda de forma automática

Comment: Te toca usar opciones complicadas porque para eso es el captcha. Tienes que reconocer las imágenes y jugar a que le ganas al servidor. Es la única forma de evadir el captcha _legalmente_. E incluso ahí, **puede que termines en problemas legales por abusar del sitio** y usarlo como no está establecido.

Comment: Si haces publicaciones que no se ajustan al sitio, mejor eliminalas. Si varias publicaciones tuyas terminan cerradas y con puntuación negativa en algún momento perderás [el privilegio de preguntar](/help/question-bans).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

La solución te la deje en este [hilo](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/PHP/2171305-API-consulta-rif-seniat-Venezuela.html#last)

Revisa y comentas

Comment: Considera dejar un comentario en lugar de una respuesta si no vas a responder en este sitio.

Comment: Vale, mañana edito la respuesta y coloco todos los pasos a seguir

Comment: Mil gracias @JeffersonJimenez seguí al pie de la letra todos los pasos y me sorprendió lo elaborado de tu código. Funciono al mil %. Eternamente agradecido